# How to get selected project from Navigator view in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm using to get the selected project from Project Explorer an ISelection that focuses the Project Explorer window:

```
IProject project = null;    





    ISelectionService  selectionService=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

    ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProjectExplorer");    



    if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {    
        Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();    

        if (element instanceof IResource) {    
            project= ((IResource)element).getProject();    

        }  
        else if (element instanceof IPackageFragmentRoot) {    
            IJavaProject jProject = ((IPackageFragmentRoot)element).getJavaProject(); 
            project = jProject.getProject();
        }
        else if (element instanceof IJavaElement) {    
            IJavaProject jProject= ((IJavaElement)element).getJavaProject();    
            project = jProject.getProject();    
        }
```

I need to focus the selection on Navigator, I tried org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.Navigator in getSelection method but it didn't worked....

How to get the selected project from Navigator view ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The id for the Navigator view is:

```
org.eclipse.ui.views.ResourceNavigator
```

For the Project Explorer view it is

```
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer
```

Comment: How can I take the current selected view: Project explorer or Navigator view  ?

Comment: You can use `IPartService.getActivePart()` to get the active part (but this might be an editor). You can use the `IPartListener2` listener to listen for active part changes so you can remember the last active view.

Comment: But can I check if the active part is Project Explorer or Navigator ?

Comment: You can use `IWorkbenchPart.getSite().getId()` to get the id of the active part.